# how to use ngx-translate with formly-form to display dynamic error message

Tags: angular, ngx-translate, angular-formly, ngx-formly

I am using formly in my angular application and ngx-translate for language translation. I have multiple form controls with some custom validation.

I want to display error messages based on input field title e.g: "First Name is Required", "Last Name is Required".

I tried using translate.stream() method, but I'm only able to display "is Required" and not able to add form control label before this.

Any suggestions will be very helpful.

Thank You.

```js
// form.json
[
  {
    "fieldGroupClassName": "row",
    "key": "applicantDetailsForm",
    "wrappers": [
      "panel"
    ],
    "templateOptions": {
      "label": "Applicant Details"
    },
    "fieldGroup": [
      {
        "key": "salutationCode",
        "type": "salutationList",
        "defaultValue": "",
        "className": "col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-12",
        "templateOptions": {
          "required": true,
          "label": "form.salutation",
          "options": [],
          "modelObjkey": "applicantDetails",
          "key": "salutationCode",
          "respkey": "salutationDesc",
          "subFieldTypeVal": "ddl",
          "disabled": true
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "firstName",
        "type": "alphaOnly",
        "defaultValue": "",
        "className": "col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-12",
        "templateOptions": {
          "required": true,
          "label": "form.firstName",
          "type": "text",
          "maxLength": 20,
          "pattern": "^([A-Za-z]+ )+[A-Za-z]+$|^[A-Za-z]+$",
          "modelObjkey": "applicantDetails",
          "key": "firstName",
          "disabled": true
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]

//module.ts
export function registerTranslateExtension(translate: TranslateService) {
  return {
    validationMessages: [
      {
        name: 'required',
        message() {
          return translate.stream('form.isrequired');
        },
      },
    ],
    extensions: [{
      name: 'translate',
      extension: new TranslateExtension(translate),
    }],
  };
}

export function requiredValidationMessage(err, field) {
  let fieldVal = field.templateOptions.labelName ? field.templateOptions.labelName : field.templateOptions.label
  return `${fieldVal} is required`;
}

imports:[
  FormlyModule.forRoot({
      extras:
      validationMessages: [
        { name: 'required', message: requiredValidationMessage }
       ]
       })
],
 providers: [
    { provide: FORMLY_CONFIG, multi: true, useFactory: registerTranslateExtension, deps: [TranslateService] },
  ]
```

[image: SS]